# jQuery parent next doesn't seem to work

Tags: jquery

I am struggling with one problem I can't handle, I have a table with records from my Database, it is created through a while loop, so they all looks the same. The problem is with a simple .delete click then .warning fadein function all divs with the same class will appear, but I need a code that only one div will appear. Hope you understood.

HTML code:

```
<td>
  <img class='delete' title='Delete Row' alt=\"Delete\" src='css/images/delete.png'/>
  <div class='warning'>Are you sure you want to delete this record ?<br/>
    <a id='yes' href=\"delete_client.php?column1=".$row['client_id']."\">Yes</a>
    <a id='no'>No</a>
  </div>
</td>
<br/>
<td>
  <img class='delete' title='Delete Row' alt=\"Delete\" src='css/images/delete.png'/>
  <div class='warning'>Are you sure you want to delete this record ?<br/>
    <a id='yes' href=\"delete_client.php?column1=".$row['client_id']."\">Yes</a>
    <a id='no'>No</a>
  </div>
</td>
<br/>
<td>
  <img class='delete' title='Delete Row' alt=\"Delete\" src='css/images/delete.png'/>
  <div class='warning'>Are you sure you want to delete this record ?<br/>
    <a id='yes' href=\"delete_client.php?column1=".$row['client_id']."\">Yes</a>
    <a id='no'>No</a>
  </div>
</td>
```

I tried this jQuery code, but it doesn't seem to work, because nothing appears.

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next('.warning').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do this -

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.warning').fadeIn('slow');
});
```